# ARM Thumb-2, GCC, code changes, and the `stmdaeq` instruction

Tags: gcc, assembly, embedded, thumb

I'm using and STM32F4 (Cortex-M4) MCU and compiling with arm-none-eabi-g++ (I'm using C++).

I have a requirement to reduce the amount of time it takes to upload my binary to the MCUs flash memory.  I have figured out I can do this by only uploading changes to my binary between modifications.  However, the compiler is generating some interesting code that is making this impossible.

Consider the following 2 programs:

(1)

```
int main()
{
    printf("hello");
    return 0
}
```

(2)

```
int main()
{
    //printf("hello");
    return 0
}
```

By simply removing the `printf` call, the binary is drastically different.  I can see this by disassembling the code using `arm-none-eabi-objdump -D mybinary`.  Here's a sample of the differences in WinMerge:

[image]

As can be seen in the image, almost all functions have a slightly different `stmdaeq` instruction, and I want to know more about this.

An answer to this question will include the following:

- I know what the `stmdaeq` instruction is, but why is it at the end of nearly all functions?  Is this the function's epilogue?
- Is there anything I can do (compiler options or otherwise) to ensure that minor code changes, like my example above, don't cause such changes throughout the entire binary?

I'm using the [GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors](https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded) GCC toolchain.

Your help will be most appreciated.

Comment: Your attempt is probably futile.  In practice, although large chunks of code may remain unchanged in terms of instructions, they will almost certainly normally change address as code is inserted or removed.  Moreover Flash memory is block erased, so the chances of no changes within a particular block are minimal - you'd have to erase and write the entire block in any case.  Depending on the exact part the actual Flash block size can be very large.  You may get further by applying aggressive size optimisation and directing the linker to fill unused spaces with 0xFF.

Comment: @Clifford, you are correct that you must write an entire block even if 1 byte is modified.  I've already accommodated for that in my flash program.  @Seva Alekseyev was right on.  The `stmdaeq` lines are actually addresses inserted at link time.  I found that by painstakingly organizing and sorting the symbols in my linker script I can get the binary to be more consistent between changes and achieve my desired result.

Comment: For this small example perhaps, but on a real (and large) application?

Comment: @Clifford, Yes, but I concede that it depends on the change.  Some changes will require the entire program to be reflashed, but my linker script modifications reduced the frequency of that occurring.  It's quite nice to only have to update 1 block for a minor change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not an instruction, it's a constant in the code section. You can tell because it's right past the return statement, which is `pop ...,pc` or `bx lr`.

Its purpose? The only purpose that I can see is that it stores an address of a global variable. Most likely, it's a link-time constant - i. e. it's resolved by linker, not by the compiler. But its code is present in system functions (alloc-related, etc). So you can't get rid of it - the bytes for the constant are there in the RTL object file, along with a relocation instruction to the linker.

It's probably an artifact of C++ RTL. Try switching to C.